# Can I use a new domain to send emails from for an Email Campaign

Tags: html, email, mailer

I am trying to use a separate domain name to send emails from. But when I using like mail@marketingwebsite.com , the email goes to spam folder. About the actual domain (mail@website.com) it working good , I need to be able to communicate to clients without emails going to spam with the new domain. Any Advice's would be appreciated.

Comment: Classifying a mail as a spam is dependent on the receiver's mail client not yours.

Comment: This is just my opinion - I believe that spam classification algorithm needs time to identify that a particular domain is not a fake. Thus you will face trouble for initial few clients irrespective of whatever domain you use. Later as the machine learns as people stop classifying your mail as spam, your mails will not go into the spam folder. One of the reasons why in promo/news mails they mention in the end to mark them as your contact so they aren't classified as spam

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that even if your mail server website.com allows you to send email as *@marketingwebsite.com the receiver will match the mail server name and the email address and if they do not match it will put the message in spam. 
You can mitigate the issue by leaving mail@website.com and working on the Displayed Name of the message.